# nodeJS: git pull, commit and push with child process

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to git pull, commit and push from nodeJS with child_process - is this suppose to work?

```
var cmd = require('child_process');
var commmandString = "cd c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MenuMakerServer\\experiments\\editormenu && git commit -am 'menu.json changes'    && git push origin main";

 cmd.exec(commmandString , function (error: any, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            callback(error.stack, null);
        }
    });
```

EDIT:

OK,
I managed to get this to work:

```
var sys = require('sys')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }

var options = {cwd:"c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MenuMakerServer\\projects\\editormenu"};

exec("git status && git pull && git commit -am 'menu changed' && git push", options, puts);
```

Comment: No that won't work... it looks like you are combining both DOS shell commands and Unix shell commands.  Specifically `c:\ ` is DOS and using `&&` to chain commands is Unix shell.  Which environment are you using?

Comment: mmm... i guess that using cygwin (new to it) made me confused..

Comment: works now - should i delete the questions? (tnx.btw)

Comment: You should post your (correct) `cwd` solution as an answer and accept it. :)

Comment: Guy - I agree with @minitech

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that won't work... it looks like you are combining both DOS shell commands and Unix shell commands. Specifically `c:\` is DOS and using && to chain commands is Unix shell. Which environment are you using?

If you are using `DOS` then you need make a `.bat` and call the batch.  This is nice becasuse you can use parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Define a node.js module something like below code.

```
exports.series = function(cmds, callback){
    var execNext = function(){
        exports.exec(cmds.shift(), function(error){
            if (error) {
                callback(error);
            } else {
                if (cmds.length) execNext();
                else callback(null);
            }
        });
    };
    execNext();
};
```

Then you can run it:

```
myProcessor.series([
    'cd c:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MenuMakerServer\\experiments\\editormenu'
    'git commit -am "menu.json changes"',
    'git push origin main '
], function(err){
   console.log('executed many commands in a row'); 
});
```

NOTE: Here myProcessor is the require variable name (somethig like `var myProcessor = require('./path/to/above/code/file');`) for the above code snippet.

Comment: But here might be dos command will not work. This is a process to execute multiple commands.

Comment: recursion seems unnecessary why not iterate?

Comment: @Hogan: It’s asynchronous.